# How to write 3 long eqs. in pretty look view?

Tags: equations, align, amsmath

I have 3 long equations and I want to write them in pretty view. they look ugly now, any help?
also there is a problem,I have used `\left[` in the first line of the third equation, then used `\\`,  in the next line when I use`\right]` it give an error and don't display the second bracket, Hoe can I fix that?

the output is this,

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{extreport}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{flexisym}    % I don't know what is this package, could you tell me what is it?
\newcommand{\p}{\partial}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
&\frac{\p}{\p \theta}\left(\bar{h}_0^3 \frac{\p\bar{p}_3}
{\p\theta}\right)+\left(\frac{D}{L}\right)^2 \frac{\p}{\p \bar{z}} 
\left(\bar{h}_0^3 \frac{\p \bar{p}_3}{\p \bar{z}}\right)+\frac{\p}{\p 
\theta}\left(3\bar{h}_0^2 \cos\theta \frac{\p\bar{p}_{1}}{\p \theta}\right)+ 
\notag \\ 
&\left(\frac{D}{L}\right)^2 \frac{\p}{\p \bar{z}} \left(\bar{h}_0^2 
\cos\theta \frac{\p \bar{p}_{1}}{\p \bar{z}}\right)+\frac{\p}{\p 
\theta}\left(3\bar{h}_0\cos\theta^2 \frac{\p\bar{p}_{0}}{\p \theta}\right) 
+\notag\\
&\left(\frac{D}{L}\right)^2 \frac{\p}{\p \bar{z}} \left(\bar{h}_0 
\cos\theta^2 \frac{\p \bar{p}_{0}}{\p \bar{z}}\right) =  0 \label{eq:p3}\\
&\frac{\p}{\p \theta}\left(\bar{h}_0^3 \frac{\p\bar{p}_4}{\p \theta}\right) 
+ \left(\frac{D}{L}\right)^2 \frac{\p}{\p \bar{z}} \left(\bar{h}_0^3 
\frac{\p \bar{p}_4}{\p \bar{z}}\right)+\frac{\p}{\p 
\theta}\left(3\bar{h}_0^2 \sin\theta \frac{\p\bar{p}_{2}}{\p \theta}\right)+ 
\notag \\ 
&\left(\frac{D}{L}\right)^2 \frac{\p}{\p \bar{z}} \left(\bar{h}_0^2 
\sin\theta \frac{\p \bar{p}_{2}}{\p \bar{z}}\right)+\frac{\p}{\p 
\theta}\left(3\bar{h}_0\sin\theta^2 \frac{\p\bar{p}_{0}}{\p \theta}\right) 
+\notag\\
&\left(\frac{D}{L}\right)^2 \frac{\p}{\p \bar{z}} \left(\bar{h}_0 
\sin\theta^2 \frac{\p \bar{p}_{0}}{\p \bar{z}}\right) =  0  \label{eq:p4}\\
&\frac{\p}{\p \theta}\left(\bar{h}_0^3 \frac{\p\bar{p}_5}{\p \theta}\right) 
+ \left(\frac{D}{L}\right)^2 \frac{\p}{\p \bar{z}} \left(\bar{h}_0^3 
\frac{\p \bar{p}_5}{\p \bar{z}}\right) + \frac{\p}{\p \theta}\left[   
3\bar{h}_0^2 \left(\cos\theta \frac{\p\bar{p}_{2}}{\p \theta} +\notag \\
&\sin\theta \frac{\p\bar{p}_{1}}{\p \theta}\right)\right]  + \left(\frac{D}
{L}\right)^2 \frac{\p}{\p \bar{z}} \left[ \bar{h}_0^2\left( \cos\theta 
\frac{\p \bar{p}_{2}}{\p \bar{z}} + \sin\theta \frac{\p \bar{p}_{1}}{\p 
\bar{z}}\right)\right] +\notag \\
&\frac{\p}{\p \theta} \left(\bar{h}_0 \cos\theta\: \sin\theta \:\frac{\p 
\bar{p}_{0}}{\p \theta}\right) +
\left(\frac{D}{L}\right)^2 \frac{\p}{\p \bar{z}} \left(\bar{h}_0 
\cos\theta\: \sin\theta \:\frac{\p \bar{p}_{0}}{\p \bar{z}}\right) =  
0\label{eq:p5}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: your example just gives the error `! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \p` and does not produce the image shown.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I forgot to defined the macro `\p`, I'll edit the question.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle it is better to comment the 3rd equation and compile then uncomment the 3rd equation and compile it again, these steps will produce the image above

Comment: @DavidCarlisle well my style was to put the equations in left alignment, but it was ugly.

Comment: but if you wanted that you just want multline and the fleqn option, there is no point to `align` if you don't have any alignment points

Comment: I used multline but there was no line break (i.e. every equations was written in one line), if it is possible to show me how it would be with multline?

Comment: you line break with `\\ ` just as in `align` the difference is there are no `&` as there is no alignment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were using `align` but not specifying any real alignment points, also you can not use left/right over a line but in almost all cases it is better to use fixed sizes anyway. I used `\bigl` and `\bigr` here you may prefer slightly larger `\Bigl` or `\biggl` ....

I also took an extra line to avoid splitting the inner term (it no longer generated an error when `\left/\right` removed but didn't look nice split).

Rather than use `\notag` you could mark it up as just three numbered rows in the align, with the left hand side being further split (eg with `aligned` but I didn't do that here.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{extreport}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
\let\p\partial

\begin{align}
\frac{\p}{\p \theta}\bigl(\bar{h}_0^3 \frac{\p\bar{p}_3}
{\p\theta}\bigr)+\bigl(\frac{D}{L}\bigr)^2 \frac{\p}{\p \bar{z}} 
\bigl(\bar{h}_0^3 \frac{\p \bar{p}_3}{\p \bar{z}}\bigr)+\frac{\p}{\p 
\theta}\bigl(3\bar{h}_0^2 \cos\theta \frac{\p\bar{p}_{1}}{\p \theta}\bigr)+{}\notag \\ 
\bigl(\frac{D}{L}\bigr)^2 \frac{\p}{\p \bar{z}} \bigl(\bar{h}_0^2 
\cos\theta \frac{\p \bar{p}_{1}}{\p \bar{z}}\bigr)+\frac{\p}{\p 
\theta}\bigl(3\bar{h}_0\cos\theta^2 \frac{\p\bar{p}_{0}}{\p \theta}\bigr) 
+{}\notag\\
\bigl(\frac{D}{L}\bigr)^2 \frac{\p}{\p \bar{z}} \bigl(\bar{h}_0 
\cos\theta^2 \frac{\p \bar{p}_{0}}{\p \bar{z}}\bigr) &=  0 \label{eq:p3}\\
\frac{\p}{\p \theta}\bigl(\bar{h}_0^3 \frac{\p\bar{p}_4}{\p \theta}\bigr) 
+ \bigl(\frac{D}{L}\bigr)^2 \frac{\p}{\p \bar{z}} \bigl(\bar{h}_0^3 
\frac{\p \bar{p}_4}{\p \bar{z}}\bigr)+\frac{\p}{\p 
\theta}\bigl(3\bar{h}_0^2 \sin\theta \frac{\p\bar{p}_{2}}{\p \theta}\bigr)+{}
\notag \\ 
\bigl(\frac{D}{L}\bigr)^2 \frac{\p}{\p \bar{z}} \bigl(\bar{h}_0^2 
\sin\theta \frac{\p \bar{p}_{2}}{\p \bar{z}}\bigr)+\frac{\p}{\p 
\theta}\bigl(3\bar{h}_0\sin\theta^2 \frac{\p\bar{p}_{0}}{\p \theta}\bigr) 
+{}\notag\\
\bigl(\frac{D}{L}\bigr)^2 \frac{\p}{\p \bar{z}} \bigl(\bar{h}_0 
\sin\theta^2 \frac{\p \bar{p}_{0}}{\p \bar{z}}\bigr) &=  0  \label{eq:p4}\\
\frac{\p}{\p \theta}\bigl(\bar{h}_0^3 \frac{\p\bar{p}_5}{\p \theta}\bigr) 
+ \bigl(\frac{D}{L}\bigr)^2 \frac{\p}{\p \bar{z}} \bigl(\bar{h}_0^3 
\frac{\p \bar{p}_5}{\p \bar{z}}\bigr) + {}\notag\\
\frac{\p}{\p \theta}\bigl[   
3\bar{h}_0^2 \bigl(\cos\theta \frac{\p\bar{p}_{2}}{\p \theta} +%{}\notag \\
\sin\theta \frac{\p\bar{p}_{1}}{\p \theta}\bigr)\bigr]  +{}\notag\\
 \bigl(\frac{D}
{L}\bigr)^2 \frac{\p}{\p \bar{z}} \bigl[ \bar{h}_0^2\bigl( \cos\theta 
\frac{\p \bar{p}_{2}}{\p \bar{z}} + \sin\theta \frac{\p \bar{p}_{1}}{\p 
\bar{z}}\bigr)\bigr] +{}\notag \\
\frac{\p}{\p \theta} \bigl(\bar{h}_0 \cos\theta\: \sin\theta \:\frac{\p 
\bar{p}_{0}}{\p \theta}\bigr) +
\bigl(\frac{D}{L}\bigr)^2 \frac{\p}{\p \bar{z}} \bigl(\bar{h}_0 
\cos\theta\: \sin\theta \:\frac{\p \bar{p}_{0}}{\p \bar{z}}\bigr) &
=   0\label{eq:p5}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: eq(1), eq(2) looks nice, but eq(3) still not pretty, is there another way to align it?

Comment: Using`\big` to size the fences doesn't seem adequate for the terms at hand. Using either `\Big` or `\bigg` seems more appropriate.

Comment: Is it common to end a line with a binary operator (`+`)? I mostly see the binary operator at the start of the next line, but these things are field dependent.

Comment: @Aditya yes I nearly made the same comment (or changed it) but it was late at night and as it's field (and country/tradition) dependent I left it.

Answer (score 13):

To emphasize visually that the six additive terms in each equation must sum to `0`, I would place this condition at the *start* of each formula rather than tuck it away toward the very end.

I would also group the material so that there are two additive terms per line; that way, the internal structure of the formulas becomes much more readily apparent: three terms each involving partial derivatives with respect to `\theta` and `\bar{z}`, respectively. For the third equation, this approach necessitates using an additional row; I trust the gain in terms of readability is worth this change.

For added legibility, I would also add a bit of vertical whitespace between the equations.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{extreport}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for "align" environment
\newcommand{\p}{\partial}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
0 &= \frac{\p}{\p \theta}\biggl(\bar{h}_0^3 
  \frac{\p\bar{p}_3}{\p\theta}\biggr) 
  +\biggl(\frac{D}{L}\biggr)^{\!\!2} \frac{\p}{\p \bar{z}} 
  \biggl(\bar{h}_0^3 \frac{\p \bar{p}_3}{\p \bar{z}}\biggr) 
  \notag \\
&\quad +\frac{\p}{\p\theta}\biggl(3\bar{h}_0^2 \cos\theta \,
  \frac{\p\bar{p}_{1}}{\p \theta}\biggr)  
  +\biggl(\frac{D}{L}\biggr)^{\!\!2} \frac{\p}{\p \bar{z}} 
  \biggl(\bar{h}_0^2 \cos\theta \,\frac{\p \bar{p}_{1}}{\p \bar{z}}\biggr)
  \notag\\
&\quad +\frac{\p}{\p \theta}\biggl(3\bar{h}_0\cos\theta^2 \,
  \frac{\p\bar{p}_{0}}{\p \theta}\biggr) 
  +\biggl(\frac{D}{L}\biggr)^{\!\!2} \frac{\p}{\p \bar{z}} 
  \biggl(\bar{h}_0 \cos\theta^2 \,
  \frac{\p \bar{p}_{0}}{\p \bar{z}}\biggr) 
  \label{eq:p3}\\[2ex]
0 &= \frac{\p}{\p \theta}\biggl(\bar{h}_0^3 
  \frac{\p\bar{p}_4}{\p \theta}\biggr) 
  + \biggl(\frac{D}{L}\biggr)^{\!\!2} \frac{\p}{\p \bar{z}} 
  \biggl(\bar{h}_0^3 \frac{\p \bar{p}_4}{\p \bar{z}}\biggr)
  \notag \\ 
&\quad+\frac{\p}{\p\theta} \biggl(3\bar{h}_0^2 \sin\theta \,
  \frac{\p\bar{p}_2}{\p \theta}\biggr) 
  +\biggl(\frac{D}{L}\biggr)^{\!\!2} \frac{\p}{\p \bar{z}} 
  \biggl(\bar{h}_0^2 \sin\theta \,
  \frac{\p \bar{p}_2}{\p \bar{z}}\biggr)
  \notag\\
&\quad+\frac{\p}{\p \theta}\biggl(3\bar{h}_0\sin\theta^2 \,
  \frac{\p\bar{p}_{0}}{\p \theta}\biggr)
  +\biggl(\frac{D}{L}\biggr)^{\!\!2} \frac{\p}{\p \bar{z}} 
  \biggl(\bar{h}_0 \sin\theta^2 \,\frac{\p \bar{p}_{0}}{\p \bar{z}}\biggr)  
  \label{eq:p4}\\[2ex]
0 &= \frac{\p}{\p \theta}\biggl(\bar{h}_0^3 
  \frac{\p\bar{p}_5}{\p \theta}\biggr) 
  + \biggl(\frac{D}{L}\biggr)^{\!\!2} \frac{\p}{\p \bar{z}} 
  \biggl(\bar{h}_0^3 \frac{\p \bar{p}_5}{\p \bar{z}}\biggr) 
  \notag \\
&\quad + \frac{\p}{\p \theta}\biggl[3\bar{h}_0^2 
  \biggl(\cos\theta \,\frac{\p\bar{p}_2}{\p \theta} 
  +\sin\theta \,\frac{\p\bar{p}_{1}}{\p \theta}\biggr)\biggr]  
  \notag \\
&\qquad 
  + \biggl(\frac{D}{L}\biggr)^{\!\!2} \frac{\p}{\p \bar{z}} 
  \biggl[ \bar{h}_0^2\biggl( \cos\theta \,\frac{\p \bar{p}_2}{\p \bar{z}} 
  + \sin\theta \,\frac{\p \bar{p}_{1}}{\p \bar{z}}\biggr)\biggr] 
  \notag \\
&\quad+\frac{\p}{\p \theta} \biggl(\bar{h}_0 \cos\theta \sin\theta \,
  \frac{\p \bar{p}_{0}}{\p \theta}\biggr) 
  + \biggl(\frac{D}{L}\biggr)^{\!\!2} \frac{\p}{\p \bar{z}} 
  \biggl(\bar{h}_0 \cos\theta \sin\theta \,
  \frac{\p \bar{p}_{0}}{\p \bar{z}}\biggr) 
  \label{eq:p5}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This look much tidier, and easier to work through. It's hard whether this can be done to say without the context, but instead of/as well as the vertical whitespace I'd seriously consider rephrasing the surrounding text to put a line or two of text between the equations. This could be along the lines of `"by applying the constraints in Eq~\ref{eq_a} we obtain \[...\] while the result in Eq~\ref{eq_b} implies \[...\]"`.

Comment: Consider also using the `split` environment to center the equation numbers vertically for each equation.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a variation on Bernard's solution. Given the space constraints I don't think it makes much sense to align specific terms. Thus my solution looks a lot like Mico's.

I agree with Mico's comment, the left/rights and `\Bigg(lr)` becomes too large and look uneven. Here is an adjustment

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{extreport}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
%\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{esdiff}
\newcommand\DLtwo{\biggl(\frac{D}{L}\biggr)^2}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  \MoveEqLeft \diffp{}{\theta}\biggl(\bar{h}_0^3
    \diffp{\bar{p}_3}{\theta}\biggr) + \DLtwo \diffp{}{{\bar z}}
  \biggl(\bar{h}_0^3
    \diffp{\bar{p}_3}{{\bar{z}}}\biggr)+\diffp{}{\theta}\biggl(3\bar{h}_0^2
    \cos\theta \diffp{\bar{p}_{1}}{\theta}\biggr) \notag
  \\
  & + \DLtwo \diffp{}{{\bar{z}}} \biggl(\bar{h}_0^2 \cos\theta
    \diffp{\bar{p}_{1}}{{\bar{z}}}\biggr)+\diffp{}{\theta}\biggl(3\bar{h}_0\cos\theta^2
    \diffp{\bar{p}_{0}}{\theta}\biggr) \notag
  \\
  & + \DLtwo \diffp{}{{\bar{z}}} \biggl(\bar{h}_0 \cos\theta^2
    \diffp{\bar{p}_{0}}{{\bar{z}}}\biggr) = 0 \label{eq:p3}
  \\[2ex]
%%
  \MoveEqLeft \diffp{}{\theta}\biggl(\bar{h}_0^3
    \diffp{\bar{p}_4}{\theta}\biggr) + \DLtwo \diffp{}{{\bar{z}}}
  \biggl(\bar{h}_0^3
    \diffp{\bar{p}_4}{{\bar{z}}}\biggr)
  +\diffp{}{\theta}\biggl(3\bar{h}_0^2
    \sin\theta \diffp{\bar{p}_{2}}{\theta}\biggr) \notag
  \\
  & + \DLtwo \diffp{}{{\bar{z}}} \biggl(\bar{h}_0^2 \sin\theta
    \frac{\bar{p}_{2}}{\bar{z}}\biggr)+\diffp{}{\theta}\biggl(3\bar{h}_0\sin\theta^2
    \diffp{\bar{p}_{0}}{\theta}\biggr) \notag
  \\
  & + \DLtwo \diffp{}{{\bar{z}}} \biggl(\bar{h}_0\sin\theta^2
    \frac{\bar{p}_{0}}{\bar{z}}\biggr) = 0 \label{eq:p4}
  \\[2ex]
%
  \MoveEqLeft \diffp{}{\theta}\biggl(\bar{h}_0^3
    \diffp{\bar{p}_5}{\theta}\biggr) + \DLtwo \diffp{}{{\bar{z}}}
  \biggl(\bar{h}_0^3 \diffp{\bar{p}_5}{{\bar{z}}}\biggr) 
  \notag
  \\
  &+
  \diffp{}{\theta}\biggl[3\bar{h}_0^2 \biggl(\cos\theta
  \diffp{\bar{p}_{2}}{\theta} + \sin\theta
  \diffp{\bar{p}_{1}}{\theta}\biggr)\biggr] \notag
  \\
  & + \DLtwo \diffp{}{{\bar{z}}} \biggl[
    \bar{h}_0^2 \biggl( \cos\theta \diffp{\bar{p}_{2}}{{\bar{z}}} +
    \sin\theta \diffp{\bar{p}_{1}}{{\bar{z}}}\biggr)\biggr]
    \notag
    \\
    &+\diffp{}{\theta} \biggl(\bar{h}_0 \cos\theta\: \sin\theta
      \:\diffp{\bar{p}_{0}}{\theta}\biggr)
    \notag
  \\
  & + \DLtwo \diffp{}{{\bar{z}}} \biggl(\bar{h}_0 \cos\theta\:
    \sin\theta \:\diffp{\bar{p}_{0}}{{\bar{z}}}\biggr) =
  0\label{eq:p5}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. I think that using `\Bigg[lr]` in the macro `\DLtwo` generates parentheses that are unnecessarily large; `\bigg[lr]` may be more appropriate. Autosizing of the parentheses also appears to cause the "fences" in the middle row of equation (3) to be larger than in the other rows. (That's why I performed a global search-and-replace of `\left` to `\biggl` and of `\right` to `\biggr` in my answer...)

Comment: @Mico I just used what Bernard used, but I agree

Comment: @Mico updated, looks better

Comment: @daleif it looks better now, just for the 3rd eq. is it possible to reduce its lines? and it will be better to align all the equations to the left.

Comment: @MuhammadAbdulrasool you could, but having lines that long makes the math harder to read.

Comment: You are right, but if I want to, how could I do that?

Comment: @MuhammadAbdulrasool You might want to familiarize your self with the align syntax, then you'd know what to remove, something for you to do.

Answer (score 1):

I propose this code. I replaced `amsmath` with its extension `mathtools`; I also loaded the `esdiff` package which eases typing partial derivatives with its command `\diffp`, and makes the code more readable. I also defined a macro for the repetitive (D/L)².

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{extreport}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{lmodern}
    \usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage{breqn}
    %\usepackage{flexisym} % I don't know what is this package, could you tell me what is it?
    % Is loaded by `brqeqn.
    \usepackage{esdiff}
    \newcommand\DLtwo{\Biggl(\frac{D}{L}\Biggr)²}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{align}
    \diffp{}{θ}\left(\bar{h}₀³ \diffp{\bar{p}₃}{θ}\right)+ {}& \DLtwo \diffp{}{{\bar z}}
    \left(\bar{h}₀³ \diffp{\bar{p}₃}{{\bar{z}}}\right)+\diffp{}{θ}\left(3\bar{h}₀² \cosθ\diffp{\bar{p}_{1}}{θ}\right)+
    \notag \\
    & \DLtwo \diffp{}{{\bar{z}}} \left(\bar{h}₀²
    \cosθ\diffp{\bar{p}_{1}}{{\bar{z}}}\right)+\diffp{}{θ}\left(3\bar{h}₀\cos\theta² \diffp{\bar{p}_{0}}{θ}\right)+
    \notag\\
     &  \DLtwo \diffp{}{{\bar{z}}} \left(\bar{h}₀
    \cos\theta² \diffp{\bar{p}_{0}}{{\bar{z}}}\right) = 0 \label{eq:p3}\\[2ex]
    %%
      \diffp{}{θ}\left(\bar{h}₀³ \diffp{\bar{p}₄}{θ}\right)
     + {}&\DLtwo \diffp{}{{\bar{z}}} \left(\bar{h}₀³
    \diffp{\bar{p}₄}{{\bar{z}}}\right)+\diffp{}{θ}\left(3\bar{h}₀² \sinθ\diffp{\bar{p}_{2}}{θ}\right) + 
    \notag \\
    &  \DLtwo \diffp{}{{\bar{z}}} \left(\bar{h}₀²
    \sinθ\frac{\bar{p}_{2}}{\bar{z}}\right)+\diffp{}{θ}\left(3\bar{h}₀\sin\theta² \diffp{\bar{p}_{0}}{θ}\right) + 
    \notag\\
    &  \DLtwo \diffp{}{{\bar{z}}} \left(\bar{h}₀\sin\theta² \frac{\bar{p}_{0}}{\bar{z}}\right) = 0 \label{eq:p4}\\[2ex]
    %
    \diffp{}{θ}\left(\bar{h}₀³ \diffp{\bar{p}₅}{θ}\right)
   +  {}& \DLtwo \diffp{}{{\bar{z}}} \left(\bar{h}₀³
    \diffp{\bar{p}₅}{{\bar{z}}}\right) + \diffp{}{θ}\biggl[3\bar{h}₀² \biggl(\cosθ\diffp{\bar{p}_{2}}{θ}
    + \sinθ\diffp{\bar{p}_{1}}{θ}\biggr)\biggr] + {} \notag\\
     &  \!\begin{aligned}[t]\DLtwo \diffp{}{{\bar{z}}} \Biggl[ \bar{h}₀²   \Biggl( \cosθ\diffp{\bar{p}_{2}}{{\bar{z}}}+
     & \sinθ\diffp{\bar{p}_{1}}{{\bar{z}}}\Biggr)\Biggr]\\[-0.5ex]
    {} &+\diffp{}{θ} \left(\bar{h}₀ \cosθ\: \sinθ\:\diffp{\bar{p}_{0}}{θ}\right) +\end{aligned} \notag \\
     &  \DLtwo \diffp{}{{\bar{z}}} \left(\bar{h}₀
    \cosθ\: \sinθ\:\diffp{\bar{p}_{0}}{{\bar{z}}}\right) = 0\label{eq:p5}
    \end{align}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The screenshot and the code don't seem to be in full agreement. E.g., the \DLtwo macro is defined as `\Biggl(\frac{D}{L}\Biggr)^2`, but the screenshot appears to indicate that `\bigg` is in effect.

Comment: What is mathtools even used for in the example or breqn for that matter. Also there is no need to load amsfonts, amssymb does that automatically.

Comment: @daleif: I almost systematically load math tools in the place of amsmath. A first try with `multlined` required it. As to `breqn`and `amsfonts`, they were in the O.P.'s post, and I didn't even think of checking…

Comment: Ahh didn't even see those packages in the OPs post.

Comment: @Mico: I've just checked, as I might have copied the code before the final version, but, no, it's really the screenshot with `\Bigg`.

Comment: @daleif: Furthermore, the O.P. asks what is `flexisym` , and I give a short answer in a comment in the code.

Comment: I'm not a big fan of aligning on the `+`'s, I just testet it think it looks better (less clunky) using three `\MoveEqLeft`, then the space on both sides look a bit more even

Comment: Yes, `flexisym` is the package that messes with all math symbols such that `breqn` can do its thing.

Comment: Actually, what I was interested in was the alignment of the `(D/L)²`, to emphasize a sort of regularity in the structure of  all these formulae. That's why there's an `aligned` environment in the 3rd series, instead of a initial `\MoveEqLeft[5]` or something.

Comment: @daleif: Finally, I managed to have the  formerly aligned `+` at the end of the line above, while not overflowing into the margin. That 14pt size is indeed a problem!

Comment: @Bernard, denenitely not a fan of ending the lines by `+` I'll post my variation of your solutin

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43402/discussion-between-bernard-and-daleif).

Comment: @Bernard it is look better now, except for the last one, is there any chance to merge the 4th line with the 3rd line? it will be very nice then.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to suggest factoring out the distributed (D/L)<sup>2</sup> term and outermost partial derivative.  If I do this, starting from Mico's code, I can fit the first equation on two lines, and I think it makes the structure significantly clearer.  For instance, the fact that there are no factors of 3 on the second line is now jarringly obvious (are you sure the terms subject to ∂/∂θ aren't supposed to be the same as the terms subject to ∂/∂z̅, apart from the change of inner differential?) and so is the absence of ∂p̅<sub>1</sub>/∂■ (I see that that shows up in the third equation, so it's probably supposed to be that way).

I've also introduced a `\pd` macro to reduce typing, and improved horizontal alignment in both the source and the typeset form.  Someone who understands the `align` environment better than me might be able to do this without resorting to `\phantom` quite so much.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{extreport}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for "align" environment
\newcommand{\pd}[2]{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
  0 &=\quad\phantom{\biggl(\frac{D}{L}\biggr)^{\!\!2}}
  \pd{}{\theta}
  \biggl(
        \bar{h}_0^3                \pd{\bar{p}_3}{\theta}
     + 3\bar{h}_0^2 \cos\theta   \,\pd{\bar{p}_1}{\theta}
     + 3\bar{h}_0   \cos\theta^2 \,\pd{\bar{p}_0}{\theta}
  \biggr)
\notag\\&\quad
+ \biggl(\frac{D}{L}\biggr)^{\!\!2}
  \pd{}{\bar{z}}
  \biggl(
                   \bar{h}_0^3                \pd{\bar{p}_3}{\bar{z}}
     + \phantom{3} \bar{h}_0^2 \cos\theta   \,\pd{\bar{p}_1}{\bar{z}}
     + \phantom{3} \bar{h}_0   \cos\theta^2 \,\pd{\bar{p}_0}{\bar{z}}
  \biggr)
\label{eq:p3}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image: rendered equation from above TeX source]

Comment: you are right I missed to write `3` for all terms except the first two terms with `\bar{h}_0^3 `, these terms don't have `3`.